# Pass selected values to node add form

Tags: 8, nodes, views

I have a view of nodes.  I'd like to be able to select rows (thinking VBO is the best) and pass those selected nodes to a form (specifically /node/add/payments) to pre-populate entity references.

Any thoughts on how to do this?  I've been playing around with several options and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, you could do something like this with a custom module:

- Create a custom VBO action ([see docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/views-bulk-operations-vbo)) to take action on your selected nodes.
- Have your custom VBO action redirect to `/node/add/payments` with some query parameter that encodes your selected nodes (e.g. `/node/add/payments?my_nids=1,2,3`).
- Add `hook_form_alter()` invocation in your module to read this query parameter (e.g. `$nids = explode(',', \Drupal::request()->request->get('my_nids')`) and pre-populate the entity ref field with your values.